# Unauthorized access to Github

Tags: github, maven

I am trying to build the application Roda and following this guide: https://github.com/keeps/roda/blob/master/documentation/Developers_Guide.md

After some time I run into this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project roda-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.roda-project:roda-core:jar:4.6.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.roda-project:commons-ip2:jar:2.3.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.roda-project:commons-ip2:jar:2.3.0: 
Could not transfer artifact org.roda-project:commons-ip2:pom:2.3.0 from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/keeps/*): Authentication failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/keeps/*/org/roda-project/commons-ip2/2.3.0/commons-ip2-2.3.0.pom 401 Unauthorized
```

I am not a Maven specialist. Help to pass this problem would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

/Paul

Update: The code above represents the lastest release Roda 4, but when trying to build the older version Roda 3, maven does not fail. Perhaps some protection of ongoing development?

Comment: Updates to the question should be made to the question itself, using the EDIT button. Making the question itself better is very good and strongly encouraged.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? I can see you've found earlier versions work, so have you looked into the dependency differences between these versions, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in this link: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token

In short. To access Maven Github packages there is a compulsory authentication.

/Paul